# Displaying JSON Data from URL using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode6, afnetworking

I want to display json data from a URL.
Everything Works the data array is accessible in only did load section. When I use it to count count it gives NULL but inside did load it works. What is the issue.

.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

NSDictionary *dictArray;
NSString *title;
}
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"


#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
  NSArray *data;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sampleUrl"]
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSDictionary *weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

         data = [weather objectForKey:@"slider"];
         NSLog(@"%@",data); // Works Fine
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [av show];
     }];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  [data count]; // doesn;t work
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


dictArray = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = [dictArray objectForKey:@"title"];
  NSLog(@"%@",data); // Doesn;t work displays NULL

return cell;}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success block of AFNetworking manager, reload your tableView. Table is now loading before the web service gets response.

```
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSDictionary *weather = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

     data = [weather objectForKey:@"slider"];
     NSLog(@"%@",data); // Works Fine
     [yourTableView reloadData];

 }
```

Comment: I want to load images form url in table view. I am using This method

Comment: NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [dictArray objectForKey:@"image"]]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    
    
    cell.imageView.image =image;

Comment: But the image loads very slowly and freez the screen what should i do

Comment: Slow loading is because of slow internet or heavy image. For screen freeze, use a third party library called SDWebImage. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: can it be possibile to acheive this with the help of AFNetwroking

Comment: I think it is possible through asynchronous request.

Comment: in my above code   [dictArray objectForKey:@"image"]; gives me the image path how can i use it/ @Fawad Masud